# Async validation with Reactive forms on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to verify if a name is present in the database. If so, I want to mark it as invalid and inform to the user this occurrence.

Besides this, I'm looking for the best approach to do this: template driven forms or reactive forms.

Note that I'm using multiple forms like the examples in https://material.angular.io.

Here's my current code:

**HTML**:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [@.disabled]="true" #stepper>
  <mat-step label="Example" [stepControl]="nameForm">
    <form [formGroup]="nameForm">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>NAME</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Input name" formControlName="name">
      </mat-form-field>
      <button
        matTooltip="Verify name in data base"
        (click)="validateName()" <<<< LOOK, HERE IS THE POINT
        [disabled]="!loading">Validate Name
        <i class="ml-2 fa fa-refresh fa-spin" *ngIf="!loading"></i>
      </button>

      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step label="Endereço" [stepControl]="enderecoForm">
    <form [formGroup]="nameForm2">
      <mat-form-field>
        ...
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </mat-step>

... more steps with one form inside of each one
```

**TS**:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private readonly _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.nameForm = this._formBuilder.group(
      {
        name: ['', Validators.required],
      },
      { validator: this.validateName },
    ); // AND HERE LOOK
    this.nameForm2 = this._formBuilder.group({
      name2: ['', Validators.required],
      // ... more forms and controls validators with reactive forms
    });
  }

  validateName(fb: FormGroup) {
    const nameCtrl = fb.get('name');
    // method verifyName return the name from database if exists
    const name = this.nameService.verifyName(nameCtrl);

    if (nameCtrl.errors == null || 'exists' in nameCtrl.errors) {
      if (name == null) {
        nameCtrl.setErrors(null);
      } else {
        nameCtrl.setErrors({ exists: true });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, can you answer me these questions: from where comes the variable `confirmSenhaCtrl`? Do you want to validate only after button click? Could you post at least the signature of the `nameServive.verifyName` function?

Comment: sorry, i fix it , updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand if you want to validate using [**`AsyncValidator`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidator) or after clicking a button, but here we go:

### 1. To validate through `asyncValidators`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { Observable, of as just } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some-component.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {
  readonly formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
    {
      name: ['', Validators.required, this.validateName]
    },
    { updateOn: 'blur' }
  );

  constructor(private readonly formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  // For this case, I'd suggest you to name it something like `nameAsyncValidator`.
  // In any case it's up to you :)
  private validateName(): Observable<{ exists: boolean } | null> {
    const { errors, value } = this.formGroup.get('name')!;

    if (errors || !value) return just(null);

    return this.nameService.verifyName(value).pipe(
      catchError(() => just(null))
    );
  }
}
```

- Note that I specified `this.validateName` as the 3rd. parameter, which one is specific for `asyncValidators`.
- Also note that I used `{ updateOn: 'blur' }` to prevent unnecessary requests to the server. The requests will be fire only on blur.
- [**DEMO (full version, including loading handling and mocked version)**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xeq9br)

### 2. To validate through a button click:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

import { catchError, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some-component.html'
})
export class SomeComponent {
  readonly formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  validateName(): void {
    const nameFormControl = this.formGroup.get('name')!;
    const { errors, value } = nameFormControl;

    if (errors || !value) return;

    return this.nameService.verifyName(value).pipe(
      take(1),
      catchError(() => just(null)),
      tap(exists => nameFormControl.setErrors(exists))
    )
    .subscribe();
  }
}
```

- [**DEMO (full version, including loading handling and mocked version)**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xeq9br-rikbh5)

---

Note that as you didn't include the signature of the `nameServive.verifyName` in the question, I assumed that it returns `Observable<{ exists: boolean } | null>`.

Comment: Thanks brother, the second aproach with the button validation is what i've looking for  